# TCPDF background color

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

is there any way possible to color the cell of TCPDF table only if it has some data. look at the below image I wanna color blocks gray only if it has some data
[image]
code image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with css snippet to handle this condition.

```
td:not(:empty){
  background: gray;
}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: if I use only CSS without ':empty' property CSS applies, but after using it nothing works

Comment: Please add working html table, so we can able to answer it properly.